# How to subtract two annotated field from different table in django?

Tags: django, django-models

I am just trying to subtract  two fields from different tables but no success till now

**My model py**

```
class partdetail(models.Model):

    partnumber = models.CharField("Part Number",max_length=10)
    partweight =models.FloatField("Weight")
    partprice =models.FloatField("Price")
    partfdy =models.CharField("Foundry",max_length=10,choices = foundry_choices)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.partnumber


class incomingdetail(models.Model):


    partnumber = models.ForeignKey(partdetail,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    indate =models. DateField("Date")
    inqty=models.IntegerField("Quantity")

  class outgoingdetail(models.Model):

    partnumber = models.ForeignKey(partdetail,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    outdate =models. DateField("Date")
    dcnumber= models.IntegerField("DC number")
    outqty=models.IntegerField("Quantity")
```

**and here is my views py**

```
def home(request):


    a=incomingdetail.objects.values('partnumber__partnumber').annotate(Sum("inqty")) # for incoming table data
    b=outgoingdetail.objects.values('partnumber__partnumber').annotate(Sum("outqty")) # for outgoing table data
    tests =list(chain(a,b)) # used to join both the queries 


    return render(request,"portalone/Home.html",{'totalincome':tests})
```

I want to subtract inqty from incomingdetail and outqty from outgoingdetail to be subtracted according to the partnumber and group by partnumber

*for now i have achieved to show two queries in single table by joining them but cant able to subtract the values from two values*

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing it on the incomingdetail and outgoingdetail models, do the annotation on the common model, partdetail. You can traverse the relationship in reverse via the [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) attribute that's set on the ForeignKey field (it defaults to `[classname]_set`).

```
partdetail.objects.annotate(
    inqty=Sum('incomingdetail_set__inqty'),
    outqty=Sum('outgoingdetail_set__outqty'),
).annotate(
    qty=F('inqty') - F('outqty')
)
```

This query likely won't work if you have missing values in which Sum is None. So you may want to use some [conditional expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/conditional-expressions) to cover that.

Also the standard practice way of naming models would be:

```
class PartDetail(models.Model):
    # Use underscores where you'd typically use spaces.
    part_number = models.CharField("Part Number",max_length=10)

class IncomingDetail(models.Model):
    # This field really should be part_detail since it's an instance of that model when you access it.
    part_number = models.ForeignKey(PartDetail,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    # You're on the IncomingDetail model, it seems logical to assume that the date field is the incoming date.
    date = models. DateField("Date")
    qty = models.IntegerField("Quantity")

class OutgoingDetail(models.Model):
    part_number = models.ForeignKey(PartDetail,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    date = models. DateField("Date")
    qty = models.IntegerField("Quantity")
```